# Entanglement and Black holes

Tags: black-holes, entropy, quantum-entanglement

If you have two entangled quantum states, One state falls into a black hole and you measure the other state, What can you say about the state that has fallen into the black hole?

If you have billions of these entangled pairs and one partner of each falls into the black hole, If you don't measure the states outside the BH , Can we say that the BH has a very large entropy? If we add more and more entanglements, Can the entropy increase without a limit?

If we measure all the partners outside the event horizon, Will the entropy of the BH decrease to zero?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28328/2451 and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33331/2451