# Quantum entanglement and black holes

Tags: quantum-mechanics, black-holes

If a particle pair has particle A fall into a black hole does that mean for particle B time stops?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28328

Comment: "*If a particle pair has particle A fall into a black hole*" - In the frame of B, A never crosses the horizon. In any other outside frame, A never crosses the horizon. With this in mind, your question is moot the way it is phrased. However, it can be rephrased in a meaningful way in terms of time slowing down near the horizon, so +1

Answer (score 0):

No, entanglement only implies a correlation between certain measurements performed on the two particles. It does not allow any type of information transfer. In other words, doing something to A will have no effect on B, at least not an effect that can be observed.

Comment: So entanglement could not be used to measure what's inside a black hole?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: @JohnPryme Even if entanglement could be used to measure what's inside a black hole, there still would be no way to put an entangled particle there. In any external frame of reference, nothing ever crosses the horizon according to the Schwarzschild solution. All we can observe or measure is stuff quickly fading away while it remains at the horizon forever.

Comment: So Hawkings radiation just gives the temperature of the black hole and has nothing to do with any "information" which is contained in it, resulting in the black hole information paradox?

Comment: @JohnPryme If nothing crosses the horizon, then there is no Hawking radiation and no information paradox.