# What happens to entangled particles at a Black Hole?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, black-holes, quantum-entanglement, event-horizon

I am probably going to ask this wrong, so please don't flame me.  I am not a scientist or student....

If an entangled particle enters an event horizon but has not reached the singularity, can we still use its partner to perform measurements on it?  Or is the entanglement broken immediately upon crossing the event horizon?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can two particles remain entangled even if one is past the event horizon of a black hole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28328/)

Comment: Why so hasty? The other question is about whether or not the entanglement of the two particles is broken when they are either side of the event horizon. Yes or no? This question is mainly about would it be possible to learn information about the inside particle by observing the outside particle? The answer is not necessarily that it is impossible because the entanglement is broken. In fact it is impossible to learn information about the state of the internal particle *even if the particles remain entangled*  so the main crux of this question is *not about the intactness of the entanglement.*

Comment: This question can be paraphrased as 'Can I send information out of a black hole using entangled particles or is the entanglement broken'? The OP is then sent a question where the consensus opinion is that the entanglement is not broken.  Implication: Information can be sent out of a blackhole using entangled particles because the entanglement is not broken....

Comment: .... whereas the correct answer is that information can not be be sent using using entangled particles even when there is no black hole involved and the correlations are only determined long after the event by comparing what was measured of one particle with what was measured to the other particle, which is impossible to do in this case as it would mean entering the black hole and examining the internal particle to find out the answer, which would be self defeating.

Comment: What  does "use its partner to perform measurements on it" mean?

Comment: @KDP No one is saying that information is being transmitted out of a black hole. Actually there is basically no difference here whether a black hole is involved or not. There is no way to determine if entanglement is/was "broken" in any scenario. And there is no specific time at which it's broken other than when both have interacted with a detector or similar irreversible process. The correlations (not the values) are determined when the Bell state was created, not "long after". If the entangled pair is created from Type II PDC, they will be perfectly polarization anti-correlated (ideal case).

Comment: @DrChinese I think the first part of what you you said is in agreement and I even said the phrase "even when there is no black hole involved". As far as determining correlations,, I was not talking about when they were created, but when they are confirmed by the observer.

Comment: @DrChinese Would you agree this question is more about whether entangled particles can be used to send information out of a blackhole than, whether or not the entanglement is broken?

Comment: @KDP I think the OP imagines a remaining connection between the particle in the black hole and the one outside. No one actually knows the mechanism of entanglement, so extending an example to a black hole doesn't really take you anywhere useful. A black hole is going to absorb the photon immediately, so you may as well call it a detector that isn't (can't be) read. When I test any entangled photon, I learn something about its partner - but not a lot. But I can learn any one or two things depending on my measurement choices. I don't think I have any disagreement with anything you say.

Comment: @DrChinese A little thought experiment: Lets say there is source of entangled photons that sends them in opposite directs to observers A and B that are light years apart. If A measures the polarisation of his photon then he will learn something about the polarisation of the photon B receives from the common source and can even calculate the probabilities of what B will measure depending on the measurements B chooses to make. Now B decides to try and send Morse code type messages to A by manipulating the orientation of her polarisers, but A will be completely unware of the manipulations B makes

Comment: @kdp Agreed completely. :)

Comment: and B cannot send messages that depend only on the entanglement of the photons or the manipulations of her polarisers. In other words it is impossible to send message using entanglement properties only (even when no black hole is involved) so whether or not the entanglement is broken is irrelevant and my main argument is that redirecting this question to a question about whether or not entanglement is broken at a event horizon is not a solution to the question posed and it should not have been closed.

Answer (score 0):

Anything you could learn from an observation on one particle of a maximally entangled particle pair, you could still learn even after the other enters a black hole.

To understand why this is true: Consider ANY entangled pair of particles.

1. There is no known "marker" on either that indicates whether they remain entangled or not.  Observing one therefore does not - in any known detectable manner - cause the properties of the other to change.
2. Of course, it is possible that observing one does change the other - and we simply cannot detect that with our current understanding.  However, QM does not provide any meaning to the idea that observing one particle prior to the other constitutes a "cause".  Actually, QM is completely silent on the point as to whether "A causes B" or "B causes A".

So whether you measure the outside particle before or after the black hole swallows the other one - there is no theoretical difference.

Comment: @safesphere Of course, I speaking from the angle of quantum entanglement. Its rules are mostly independent of GR. What can the outside particle tell me about the inside particle? Not a lot. If I test polarization at some angle - say 42 degrees, I will know precisely what the inside particle's polarization was while it existed. Same for wavelength, and a variety of measurements. These observations could be redundant/useless depending on your objective. ...

Comment: @safesphere However: There is no requirement that entanglement be between particles that co-exist; this has been demonstrated experimentally. And there is no theoretical sense in which time of detection (or when a particle encounters the effects of the black hole) matters. The breaking of entanglement cannot be pinned to a specific point(s) in spacetime OTHER THAN by assumption. Ordering of measurements - regardless of traditional notions of causality - makes no difference to the observable outcome. I would agree that once the photon reaches the black hole horizon, it ceases to exist.

Comment: @safesphere Yes, it seems counter-intuitive. But just as it is possible to entangle photons that have never existed in a common backward light cone using Entanglement Swapping, it is possible to adjust order so that one entangled photon is detected *before* a swap occurs. And before its ultimate entangled partner is even created. See "Entanglement Between Photons that have Never Coexisted" https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.4191 *"...the non-locality of quantum mechanics, as manifested by entanglement, does not apply only to particles with spatial separation, but also with temporal separation."*

Comment: @safesphere In *any* entangled photon pair, one will be detected & cease to exist before the other anyway. So there is no good way to say when entanglement ends other than by pure assumption. With experiments as I cited where there is no overlap in a backwards light cone, the issue really becomes impossible to describe. The presence of a black hole simply causes the one photon to eventually become merged with it and it will gain energy/mass as with anything it eats. Energy is conserved. No different really than photon absorption by a bound electron, right?